# Complexity of Treemap insertion vs HashMap insertion

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

I am confused with the time complexity of these two algorithms.

```
//time complexity O(nlog(n))
public void usingTreeMap(){
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        map.put(i, i);
    }
}
//time complexity O(n)
public void usingHashMap(){
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        map.put(i, i);
    }
}
```

Is the time complexity to the usingTreeMap algorithm correct.I do know in treemap the insertion time is log(n) but if we iterate over an array of 10 elements does it become nlog(n).

Comment: You always express insertion time per element. Of course, if you insert `n` elements, you multiply that value by `n`.

Comment: HashMap is O(1) *on average*. If you happen to have a lot of collisions or have to grow the table, an *insertion* could be O(n).

Answer (score 51):

### Complexity with HashMap

In the case of HashMap, the backing store is an array. When you try to insert ten elements, you get the hash, compute the specific array index from that hash, and since it's an array in the back, you inject in O(1).

- For first element, time taken to insert = O(1)
- For second element, time taken to insert = O(1)
- .
- .
- For n<sup>th</sup> element, time taken to insert = O(1)

So, total time for insertion of n elements in a HashMap = n * O(1) = O(n)

---

### Complexity with TreeMap

In this case, the backing store is a Tree. For a tree with total *k* elements, on an average, the time to find the location is O(Log k).

- Time to insert first element = O(1)
- Time to insert second element = O(Log 1) = 0 = O(1)
- Time to insert third element = O(Log 2)
- .
- .
- Time to insert n<sup>th</sup> element = O(Log (n-1))

Total time = Log 1 + Log 2 + Log 3 + ... + Log (n-1)

Now, Log 1 <= Log n, Log 2 <= Log n ... Log (n-1) <= Log n, leading us to n-1 values each of which is less than or equal to Log n.

This means that the timing for insertion in a treemap sum to a value <= (n-1) * Log (n), leading to the complexity of O(n Log (n)).

---

<sub>One of the properties of logs is `Log a + Log b = Log (ab)`. Using that, the insertion time in case of TreeMap sums to a lesser-known running time value of O(Log(n!)). But, since, [O(Log(n!)) is bound by O(n Log(n))](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37129449/1835769), the time complexity of insertion of n elements in a TreeMap is loosely written O(n Log(N)).</sub>

Comment: Log 1 + Log 2 + Log 3 + ... + Log (n-1) = Log ((n-1)*(n-2)*...1) = Log ((n - 1)!) = ~Log ((n - 1)^n-1)  = (n - 1)Log (n - 1) = ~nLog (n)

Comment: @Aspirant9: Yeah.. many ways to arrive at the same answer. :-)

Answer (score 22):

Insertion time complexity is typically defined on a per instance basis.

**Average** case:

- HashMap O(1)
- TreeMap O(log*n*) -- since the underlying structure is a red-black tree

**Worst** case:

- Hashmap O(*n*) -- in the case of a hashing collision
- TreeMap O(log*n*)

In your code above since you are inserting multiple items, we need to distinguish how many elements are in the maps (*n*) vs. how many elements are being added to the maps (*m*). If the maps are initially empty, then your runtime above is correct. If they already have some elements, then the runtimes would be:

```
                                Avg      Worst
Insert m elements into HashMap: O(m)     O(mn)
Inset m elements into TreeMap:  O(mlogn) O(mlogn)
```

Comment: If n elements are already present then wouldn't TC of TreeMap be O(mlog(m+n)) ?

Answer (score 4):

> Is the time complexity to the usingTreeMap algorithm correct.

The time complexities of the basic `TreeMap` operations are specified correctly in the Javadoc.

> I do know in treemap the insertion time is log(n)

Correct.

> but if we iterate over an array of 10 elements does it become nlog(n).

If this means inserting those 10 elements the time complexity is `M*log(N)` where `M` is the size of the array and `N` is the size of the `TreeMap.` If it doesn't mean that, the question is unclear.

Comment: but isn't m and n the same ??

Comment: @luckysing_noobster No. What `M` and `N` are is stated clearly in the answer.

Comment: @luckysing_noobster The size of the `TreeMap` is not fixed. As we inserting element the size increases like 1, 2, 3, ... to 10 in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be. (i.e. when 4 elements out of 10 have same key, then N will be 7), so I believe more duplicate keys, better time for the insertion.